# OpenCart - 404 page not found error with new module

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

OpenCart 1.5.6; Theme: Default.

I've created a new module 'Seller' cloned by 'Manufacturer' ... Admin side & Front side is working okay, means adding / editing / saving data is working okay, except an issue.

When I click on 'Seller' link at product page (frontend), it shows 404 error / page not found, ideally it should work same as Manufacturer module works, should open seller's page with list of products by the same seller.

What could be the reason? Because I don't see any error in log files / VQMOD, it just shows 404 error.

Any clue?

Comment: Make sure that the function calls are correct and the template files exists. You might have forgotten to rename a few things in code. Search for "Manufacturer" in your seller files and check yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this happened here:

Let's assume Your *seller* URL is `http://my.domain.com/index.php?route=product/seller&seller_id=1`.

Now the `route` part `product/seller` tries to load this controller file:

```
catalog/controller/product/seller.php
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and while there is no action specified (which would be e.g. `product/seller/showList`) the `index` action is called. This all means, that You need to have the above mentioned file, which has to contain a class `ControllerProductSeller` extending from `Controller` and this class has to have method `index` implemented.

This would look like

```
class ControllerProductSeller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

After this is fulfilled You should not receive a 404 error.

I can see You are completely new to OpenCart and new modules creation (reminds me of my starts) and my advice is: look and discover how the things in OpenCart are done, copy+paste+rename wisely. Most of errors like this (and missing template, language, model files, undefined method names etc) are caused by improper renaming, or in other words, by *hot head and quick fingers*... Slow down and start thinking a little bit about what are You doing and **what needs to be done**.